$V^A$ flat iff $(V^{(B)})^A$ flat
Exercise 13.19 of the book "Rings and Categories of Modules" by Anderson & Fuller asks the reader to prove that for a module $V$, the direct product $V^A=\prod _{i\in A}V$ is flat for all sets $A$ if if and only if the the direct product of the direct sum $$(V^{(B)})^A= \prod _{i\in A}(\bigoplus _{j\in B}V)$$ is flat for every sets $A$ and $B$.
The "only if" part is evidently proved by taking a one-element set $B$ and every set $A$. For the "if" part, I want to use the well-known fact that a module $P$ is flat if and only if every finitely generated submodule of $P$ is contained in a flat submodule of $P$. (This is Exercise 2 of the section dedicated to flatness  in T.Y.Lam's book "Lectures on Modules and Rings". So, let $S$ be a f.g. submodule of $(V^{(B)})^A$ generated by $s_1, \ldots , s_n$. It is sufficient to show that each $s_k$ is contained in a flat submodule of   $(V^{(B)})^A$, $(1\leq k\leq n)$. Now, as an element of $(V^{(B)})^A$, each $s_k$ is a tuple $(\sigma_i)_{i\in A}$, where each $ \sigma_i$ is an element of $ V^{(B)}=\bigoplus_BV$, whence itself a tuple all but finitely many components of which are zero. I am stuck in this very  step. Probably, $s_k$ falls into a direct sum of copies of the flat module $V^A$, but I don't know how. Does this approach work? Thanks for any help!
